# Is there a method in the standard API which can deep clone a list?

Tags: java, arraylist, clone

In about 30 days, I'm going to participate in a Java contest. At the contest, we'll be handed a computer with Eclipse and the Java 1.7 API. I'm practicing on the tasks from the previous year's contest, and I repeatedly find the need to deep clone a list. With limited time and the only the Java 1.7 API available, is there any way to do this?

I've seen several solutions to this already, including

- Implementing the `Cloneable` interface.
- Importing the Java Deep-Cloning library
- Implement a cloning constructor to the class of whatever object the `List` is holding, and iterate over the elements.

But these solutions are either not available to me at the contest or too time consuming. Right now, I need to deep clone an `ArrayList` of objects that also contain `ArrayList`s.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? Thanks for all help!

Comment: How about serializing the objects to a stream and back again?  (do they implement serializable)  eg: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-deep-clone-using-serializable.html

Comment: do you want to clone the elements as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a way to clone the `ArrayList` and all it's content, and the content of the content as well.

Comment: If you have to deep-clone, you have to clone the elements in the collection as well. Of course, in order to do this, the elements must be cloneable as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to depend entirely on what's in the List. So, the short answer is: no.

You could try serializing the whole List, but that requires everything in the List also be serializable. You could write a deepClone() method that calls the clone() method on everything in the List, but that depends on every Object in the List correctly implementing the clone() method.

The whole reason this is a contest question is there isn't a quick one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking clone you could also write everything to a ByteArrayOutputStream and read it in again.

See if this helps you:

```
  static public <T> T deepCopy(T oldObj) throws Exception {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream( bos);
      oos.writeObject( oldObj);
      oos.flush();
      ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream( bos.toByteArray());
      ois = new ObjectInputStream( bin);

      return (T) ois.readObject();
    } catch( Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw ( e);
    } finally {
      if( oos != null) {
        oos.close();
      }
      if( ois != null) {
        ois.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

Usage e. g.:

```
public class Testing {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add( "A");
    list.add( "B");
    list.add( 1);
    list.add( 2);
    list.add( new BigDecimal( 123.456839572935879238579238754938741321321321321593857));
    list.add( new MyParentObject( 12345, "abcdef", new MyChildObject( "child")));

    List clone = (List) Tools.deepCopy( list);

    for( Object obj: clone) {
      System.out.println( obj);
    }

    System.exit(0);
  }

  private static class MyParentObject implements Serializable {
    int a;
    String b;
    MyChildObject child;

    public MyParentObject(int a, String b, MyChildObject child) {
      super();
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.child = child;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return a + ", " + b + ", " + child;
    }
  }

  private static class MyChildObject implements Serializable {
    String s;

    public MyChildObject( String s) {
      this.s = s;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return s;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
1
2
123.456839572935876958581502549350261688232421875
12345, abcdef, child
```